# Which linux distro's package repositories are secure and which are not?

Tags: security, distributions, repository

Most distro's I know have some kind of repository functionality where new packages could be downloaded after installation. Which distros do this in a secure way and which doesn't do this in a secure way.

I'm especially thinking about attack vectors like man-in-middle and problems like breach of security on both the repository meta server and the repository file mirrors.

I have heard that both Slackware and Arch linux are very vulnerable because they lack package signing. Is this true? Are there any other major linux distro's that are vulnerable for simple man-in-middle attacks?

Comment: if the distro's site is cleartext http or ftp and the distro is obtained as an iso from this connection and this base connection is MITM'ed than how much good does any 'post-mortem' package signing on the update packages do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but there are several things you can do to mitigate against this risk. The simplest one is to check your downloaded packages against the checksums from a *different* mirror than you downloaded from.

When my package manager (`poldek`) downloads a package, I have it set to keep a copy of the downloaded rpm in a cache folder. It automatically checks the checksum of the download against the package repository and warns/aborts on a mismatch, but   if you were worried about man-in-the-middle attacked against your distro repository it would be easy to write a secondary script that browsed through all your downloaded packages and verify them against checksums you download from a different mirror. You can even run your first install as a dry-run so that packages get downloaded but not installed, then run your verification script, then do the actual install.

This doesn't stop a compromised package from getting into the distro's repository, but most distros have other ways of mitigating that, and even signed packages would not guarantee this was never a problem. What it does do is stifle the targeted man-in-the-middle attack vector. By using a separate source and downloading on a separate channel, you kill the ease with which a compromised package could be dropped into a tapped line.

Comment: There is a package for Arch called `paccheck` that does this, compares packages against different mirrors before installation and warns of any discrepancies.

Comment: Mirror lists are probably public, so cannot an attacker could theoretically plot to MITM all of them by pattern? If an attacker specifically targets your server then doesn't this seems even more likely? Nevertheless this is most probably more then what the Linux-majority do.

Answer (score 10):

Debian packages are checksummed, and the checksums are signed by a key in the Debian keyring.  The `apt` package manager ensures that the downloaded package has the correct checksum  and that the checksum file was signed correctly.

Answer (score 5):

Fedora packages are signed and checksummed. Even 3rd party repositories such as [rpmfusion](http://rpmfusion.org/) sign their packages.

Yum (the package manager) requires a special flag (`--nogpgcheck`) to install packages which haven't been signed.

Comment: and so does downsteam packages i.e. Red Hat and CentOS

Answer (score 2):

All Arch Linux packages use an md5 or sha1 sum to check that all the bits are in place. It's up to the package maintainer to choose the hashing algorithm. Packages installed from AUR (often just a small PKGBUILD text file) are supposed to be checked by the installee before being installed. The repositories containing the official binary packages are supervised by trusted users (TUs).

**Update**: Arch has now introduced package signing with pacman 4

Comment: All true, but packages are not signed and therefore remain vulnerable to mitm and mirror compromise attacks, however remote the possibility. It's been a long-requested feature and the main reason why I grudgingly stopped using Arch. That said, there is ongoing discussion about it in Arch and Pacman forums and wiki - it's a difficult problem to solve. Apart from this issue, Arch is a fantastic distro.

Comment: @Eli: I'm not debating the truth of this - I have no idea of the state of affairs - but wouldn't it be a vanishingly slim market to attack. Granted, Arch is quite a popular distro, but aren't all these types of mischief generally predicated upon being able to make a buck?

Comment: Sure, after all this is the reason the Windows userbase is targeted more than that of Linux, right? The thing is, what applies to the aggregate usually does not exactly apply to the individual. What I mean is everyone's threat model is different - if you have reason to fear being singled out for an attack, you should take appropriate steps to diminish the risk. Lack of package signing presents attack vectors that are not all that hard to exploit. If you have valuable bits to protect, this issue should be taken into account in your threat mitigation strategy.

Comment: You could install Arch from a CD/DVD and then just take care to check that the md5/sha1 sums of the binary packages correspond to the sums from several mirrors before installing, similar to what Caleb suggested. There's never 100% security in any case, even though I do see the point of package signing, and wish that Arch had it.

Comment: so how it is achieved that the checksum is delivered in a safer way that cleartext http or ftp? should signature-checking be in place by what means does it happen on arch exactly?

Comment: Arch has now had properly signed packages for a while, so it's no longer an issue.

Answer (score 1):

**Who said Slackware has no package signing?**

Slackware packages are signed with a public key of Slackware. So every package has its signature with extension `.asc`. Not only the packages but other files are also signed, like `CHECKSUMS.MD5`. This contains list of checksums of the packages.

The distro has an official tool called `slackpkg` for downloading/installing packages from a mirror. After updating the local repo database with `slackpkg update` the tool checks the signature validity of the new MD5 file and changelog, etc...

After downloading a package (but before installing) the signature and MD5 of the package are checked.

One can obtain the public key with `slackpkg update gpg` or simply importing it from the install CD with `gpg --import GPG-KEY`

There's an other unofficial tool `slapt-get` for Slackware. It supports GPG-checks too! In a similar way as `slackpkg`.

Answer (score -2):

OpenBSD by and far. The entire project is dedicated around security, the team even put up a 5000+ line patch to the original apache because they didn't feel it was secure enough to be used. This is via pkg_add but I've never had issues with it.

Comment: You're not answering the question: it's specifically about verifying signatures of downloaded packages (and ports, in the case of *BSD).

Comment: I agree with @Gilles; OpenBSD is a great OS, but @grm asked about Linux package distribution security.